# How to join Observables with rxjs operators in Angular (angularfire2)

Tags: angular, dictionary, rxjs, observable, angularfire2

Im trying to figure out the basics of joining Observables in Angular. I've found several examples but can't seem to figure out how to get it working efficiently.

I have the following datastructure:

```
- courses
    - $courseid1
    - $courseid2
    - $courseid3
    - ...

- teachers
    - $teacherid1
    - $teacherid2
    - $teacherid3
    - ...

- teachersPerCourse
    - $courseid1
        - $teacherid1 : true
        - $teacherid2 : true
    - $courseid2
        - $teacherid1 : true
    - $courseid3
        - $teacherid3 : true
    - ...
```

Now I'm using the following function to retrieve a course with its slug:

```
getFullCourseBySlug(slug:string) {
  return this.db.list('academy/courses', {
  query: {
    orderByChild: 'slug',
    equalTo: slug
    }
  }).map((courses) => courses[0]);
}
```

Now I wish to map an array of teachers to the course object so that I end up with an observable that emits something like this:

```
{
title: ...,
slug: ...,
teachers: {
  $teacherid1: {
    firstname: ...,
    lastname: ...,
    etc ... },
  $teacherid2: {
    firstname: ...,
    lastname: ...,
    etc ... }
  }
}
```

I've got the same principle to work in other places, but I had to use subscriptions within the map function, or work with Observables within Observables. For example:

```
getCoursesPerCategory(categoryid:string):Observable<Course[]> {
  return this.db.list(`academy/coursesPerCategory/${categoryid}`).map(courses => {
    courses.map(course => {
      this.db.object(`academy/courses/${course.$key}`).subscribe((data) => {
        course.$value = data;
      });
      return course;
    });
    return courses;
  });
}
```

If someone could help me with an example of how I could do this more efficiently that would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:

I've managed to get it to work but I still can't get rid of the nested Observables, which means that I have to use tripple Async pipes (which is probably not best practice :P) I've tried to use flatMap as suggested but can't yet figure out how to do it. What I have right now:

```
getFullCourseBySlug(slug:string): Observable<any> {
  return this.db.list('academy/courses', {
    query: {
      orderByChild: 'slug',
      equalTo: slug
    }
  }).map(courses => courses[0]).switchMap(course => {

    course.teachers = this.db.list(`academy/teachersPerCourse/${course.$key}`)
    .map(teachers => {
      teachers.map(teacher => {
        teacher.$value = this.db.object(`academy/teachers/${teacher.$key}`);
      });
      return teachers;
    });

    return  Observable.of(course);
  });
}
```

With the following template:

```
{{ (course | async)?.title }}

<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let teacher of ((course | async)?.teachers ) | async">
    {{ (teacher.$value | async)?.firstname }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

UPDATE 2:

See my answer for my solution

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is something along the following lines.

First I would build the method to query the courses, something like yours

```
getFullCourseBySlug(slug:string) {
  return this.db.list('academy/courses', {
  query: {
    orderByChild: 'slug',
    equalTo: slug
    }
  }).map((courses) => courses[0]);
}
```

Then I would create the second query you need to perform, i.e. the one that fetches the teachers Ids of the course.

The code of the query could look like

```
getTeacherIdsPerCourse(course: any) {
  return this.db.list('academy/teachersPerCourse', {
  query: {
    orderByChild: 'slug',
    equalTo: course.slug
    }
  }).map((teacherIds) => [teacherIds, course]);
}
```

Look at the fact that this second query is built to return both the teacherIds and the course which has been passed as parameter.
Now you can concatenate the 2 queries using the switchMap operator.
The concatenation would be then something like

```
this.getFullCourseBySlug(slug)
   .switchMap(course => this.getTeacherIdsPerCourse(course))
   .map(([teacherIds, course]) => {
      // here you have the TeacherIds and the course and therefore you
      // need to fetch from DB the details for each teacherId and build the 
      // full course object with all the details
    })
```

The question now is how to perform a bunch of queries and manage the resulting observables, since you need to read from the teachers collection all the teachers whose Ids have been fetched with the second query.

First of all build the third query you need, i.e. the query that fetches all details of a teacher starting from the teacher Id. The code could look like

```
getTeacher(id:string) {
  return this.db.list('academy/teachers', {
  query: {
    orderByChild: 'slug',
    equalTo: slug
    }
  }).map((teachers) => teachers[0]);
}
```

If you can live with the asynchronous return of http calls, i.e. if you do not need to wait for the last teacher to be fetched, than you could have something like this

```
this.getFullCourseBySlug(slug)
   .switchMap(course => this.getTeacherIdsPerCourse(course))
   .map(([teacherIds, course]) => {
      for(let id of teacherIds) {
         this.getTeacher(id).subscribe(teacher => {
           course.teachers.push(teacher);
         }
      }
    })
```

If, on the contrary, you need to have the full course returned with all its teachers with all their details, then you need to do something a little bit more complex since you need to wait for all the observables returned by the `getTeacher()` method to be resolved.

The code to do so could be something like

```
this.getFullCourseBySlug(slug)
   .switchMap(course => this.getTeacherIdsPerCourse(course))
   .map(([teacherIds, course]) => {
      const arrayOfObservables = new Array<Observable>();
      for(let id of teacherIds) {
         arrayOfObservables.push(this.getTeacher(id)
                                      .map(teacher => course.teachers.push(teacher)));
      }
      return Observable.combineLatest(arrayOfObservables):
    })
```

DISCLAIMER: I am not  totally sure that the code is correct since I did not build a real test but simply assembled the concepts that I think are relevant - I hope anyway I have given you an idea

Comment: This really helped me in the right direction, in the end I managed to get it working as I wished! Thanks a lot for the extensive answer and help. I'll post my final solution for other people

Answer (score 0):

Picci's answer helped me in the right direction, this is my final solution:

```
getTeachersPerCourse(courseid:string):Observable<Teacher[]> {
  return this.db.list(`academy/teachersPerCourse/${courseid}`)
  .switchMap( (teachers) => {
    let teacherObservables = [];
    for(let teacher of teachers){
      teacherObservables.push(this.db.object(`academy/teachers/${teacher.$key}`));
    }
    return Observable.combineLatest(teacherObservables);
  });
}

getFullCourseBySlug(slug:string): Observable<any> {
  return this.db.list('academy/courses', {
    query: {
      orderByChild: 'slug',
      equalTo: slug
    }
  }).map(courses => courses[0]).switchMap(course => {
    return Observable.combineLatest(Observable.of(course), this.getTeachersPerCourse(course.$key), (fullCourse, teachers) => {
      fullCourse['teachers'] = teachers;
      return fullCourse;
    });
  });
}
```

This gives me a stream with the course, and an array of teachers as child of the course:

```
{
title: ...,
slug: ...,
teachers: [
  {
    firstname: ...,
    lastname: ...,
    etc ... 
  },
  {
    firstname: ...,
    lastname: ...,
    etc ... 
  }
  ]
}
```

The Observables emit on any change of any child, just what I was looking for. And I only need to use one async pipe in my template:

```
{{ (course | async)?.title }}

<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let teacher of (course | async)?.teachers">
    {{ teacher.firstname }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps other people :)